# Subsonic with VistaDB?

Tags: subsonic, vistadb

Is it possible to use Subsonic with VistaDB? I see it as a supported database for Subsonic 3 on the project website, But can't find a T4 template for it?

Will I need to use SR or I can use AR?

Vikas

Answer (score 1):

Although the underlying architecture of SubSonic (System.Data.Common) supports VistaDB there aren't currently any templates for it. So although in theory it's supported it won't be supported in practice until someone creates those templates.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a vistadb provider for subsonic 2.x that was never made part of the official project. The main reason it's not in subsonic is that it's not freely available, the required dll for it is very encumbered with licensing. So no one wanted the hassle. You could take this provider code and use it to prepare a template, or just copy the sql server template, and make the required edits for reading the schema. I don't think that vistadb will ever be an official part of subsonic 3 since the vistadb dll is not freely available even for testing. I dropped vistadb because of performance issues.

Comment: I've been using VistaDB for nearly two years now and never had a problem with performance!